# Proposed migration of astro-photography questions from astronomy.se

Tags: discussion, migration

The Astronomy site is being [shut down](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170/astronomy-is-closing), and most of the content is being migrated to [physics.se](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/if-its-possible-do-we-want-to-expand-the-scope-of-this-site-to-include-astrono).  Some of the physics community is reluctant about taking the questions that lie farthest from astrophysics.  In discussing what to do with those questions it was suggested that [astrophotography](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography) questions be migrated here instead since there is an active [astrophotography tag](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/astrophotography) here already, and I've flagged the half that appear to be on-topic here as candidates for migration (the remainder were, despite the tag, general astronomy type questions).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Migration of astrophotography questions to PhotoSE sounds like an ok idea. I went through some of the answers, and they are excellent, demonstrating a lot of knowledge about astronomy and imaging...more so than members might get here on a regular basis. It would help if some of the astronomy members started visiting PhotoSE on a regular basis to offer their expertise for future astrophotography questions, as there is no doubt they have a wealth of information when it comes to using telescopes for imaging in general...eye or camera.

We might need to close some of them after migration, as I'm not sure all of them fit our forum well, but we can make those determinations once the content is migrated.

Comment: It should be possible to sort them in advance, since they'd be moved individually instead of in bulk minimizing the number that would end up being closed.  I flagged the 13 I felt would be on topic here.  If a few other people do the same it should be clear for the moderators/migration team which questions to send here, and which to leave behind for the bulk import to physics.se

Comment: I'm in favor of this as well.

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: Me too, which gives a unanimous verdict from the mods here :)

Comment: It is ashame the Astronomy site is being shutdown as I love astronomy. I would love to see any Astrophotography questions migrated here.

Comment: @Lynda  Most, if not all, of the questions from Astronomy will be on topic on Physics; and with its front page showing a bit more than a days worth of questions finding them among the others shouldn't be that difficult.